# How to get the parameter from url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I couldn't get the parameter value from url in codeigniter.
For instance: `localhost/log/job/php` here `log/` is my folder, `job/` is my controller and `php` is my parameter.

I want to get this parameter in controller 'job'.
How can I do that?

Comment: You may need to configure your routes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$this->uri->segment(n);`

You need to do some changes in route in order to allow the code igniter to receive the parameter in your controller

```
$route['uri-(:any)/(:num)'] = "controller/function/$1/$2";
```

**OR**

```
$route['uri-(:any)'] = "controller/function/$1";
```

in your controller do some changes

```
<?php
 if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
   exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class controller extends CI_Controller 
 {
    function function($parameter1 = null, $parameter2 = null) 
    {
       ........
    }
 }
```

refer this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 6):

You might use `$this->uri->segment(n)`.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/uri.html

Comment: thank you, If i do that it showing page not found error

Comment: You may need to configure your routes.

Comment: @wolfgang actually i don't know how to config my routes could you help me

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your parameter will be in the end always:

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();
echo end($segs);
```

EDIT: For the clarify other essentials. First you need the setup your `application/config/routes.php` :

```
$route['Youruri-(:any)/(:num)'] = "yourcontroller/yourfunction/$1/$2";
$route['Youruri-(:any)'] = "yourcontroller/yourfunction/$1";
```

In the controller `application/controllers/yourcontroller.php` you need to define a function:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Yourcontroller extends CI_Controller {

function yourfunction($brand = null, $page = null) {
   // http://www.yoursite.com/Youruri-Microsoft
   // or http://www.yoursite.com/yourcontroller/yourfunction/Microsoft
   // do some stuff for get products of this $brand (Microsoft)
   if($page != null) {
   // http://www.yoursite.com/Youruri-Intel/2 
   // or http://www.yoursite.com/yourcontroller/yourfunction/Intel/2
   // do some other stuff get products of this $brand (Intel) of $page (2)
   }
}
}
```

Comment: i tried  it just displaying controller name but not displaying my parameter

Comment: @M.Athishkrishna the code with segments always shows last part of url. I think you are not passing parameter via uri to your application.

Answer (score 2):

You get it by this:

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

where n = 1 for controller, n = 2 for method and n = 3 for parameter and so on.

You need n = 3 to get parameter.

In your path `localhost/log/job/php` , your method name is missing.

Even if your method name is `index` then you route will be `localhost/log/job/index/php`

In case if you need to remove index.php from url then you will get parameter using `localhost/log/index.php/job/index/php`

To remove index.php you need to create .htaccess file by following these steps:

1. Create a .htaccess file where index.php file is located with content

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   ```
2. Make sure that apache can access this .htaccess file. To do this edit apache configuration file. If you use ubuntu, then it is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and then change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride all` for directory and www directory.

   ```
      <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride all
      </Directory>
      <Directory /var/www/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride all
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
      </Directory>
   ```
3. Then enable mod rewrite if you don't have it, with the following command:

   ```
       `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
   ```
4. Finally do not forget to restart apache.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$param = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

add .htaccess on your folder (on your case is `"log"`) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /log/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /log/index.php/$1 [L]
```